# LINQ in VB InvalidCastException

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net

I run into this problem

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[Student]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Student]'

When I debug this function:

```
Public Shared Function SearchStudent(ByVal firstname As String) As List(Of Student)

    Dim db As New DemoDataContext()
    Dim query = From st In db.Students _
                Where (st.FirstName.StartsWith(firstname)) _
                Select st

    Return CType(query, List(Of Student))


End Function
```

My project property setting: Option explicit ON and Option strict ON

I want to return a List of Student from the query. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Dim query = (From st In db.Students _
            Where (st.FirstName.StartsWith(firstname)) _
            Select st).ToList()
```

Comment: query.ToList(Of Student) will also do the job.

Comment: I tried that option before I posted this question. But I got this error Extension method 'Public Function ToList() As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TSource)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is not generic (or has no free type parameters) and so cannot have type arguments

Comment: How about .ToList() ? I think you can omit the type parameter since it can be inferred from the usage.

Comment: Yes, I used .ToList() only and Return query. I dont understand why I can't CType query.

Comment: To my knowledge, it is because of IEnumerable which doesn't support either implicit or explicit conversion to List(Of T).

Comment: The reason is that the LINQ query is not a List!  You need to read up on deferred execution of LINQ queries.  The actual Sql query does not happen until the ToList() method is called.